# Swift - Sorting url content into an array

Tags: arrays, string, swift

So i have managed to download the content of this webpage - http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt

and i am trying to sort each word into an array like so -

```
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt")



    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, respons, error) in

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String

            var wordArr = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

            println(wordArr)


        }

    }

    task.resume()


}
```

But the problem is i am not getting each word into an array because the words are not separated by a "Space". All i'm getting is the content but as 1 item in the array.

How would i go about separating the content into an array of words. Separating the words by line breaks?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way is [`enumerateLinesUsingBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateLinesUsingBlock:) with `NSString`

```
var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var lines:[String] = []
urlContent.enumerateLinesUsingBlock { line, _ in
    lines.append(line)
}
println(lines)
```

In this specific case, you can simply split by `"\n"`:

```
var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
var lines = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
if lines.last == "" {
    // The last one is empty string
    lines.removeLast()
}
```

But in general, the line separator may not be `"\n"`. see [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getLineStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:):

> A line is delimited by any of these characters, the longest possible
>   sequence being preferred to any shorter:
>
> - `U+000D` (`\r` or `CR`)
> - `U+2028` (Unicode line separator)
> - `U+000A` (`\n` or `LF`)
> - `U+2029` (Unicode paragraph separator)
> - `\r\n`, in that order (also known as `CRLF`)

`enumerateLinesUsingBlock` can handle all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. i could have sworn i had tried \n but it gave me errors but soon as someone tells me to do it - it works. Figures lmao.

Thanks for the enumerateLinesUsingBlock thing tho!